# Excel VBA loop through filter criteria and save data as new workbok

Tags: excel, vba, loops

II’m trying to create a macro that:
- puts a auto filter on a table of data
- Loops through all the criteria in column 9
- copy the data and saves as a new workbook to a folder
- using the filter criteria as the name for the workbook

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow is not a free script writing service. Your own research and code attempts are expected. Edit the question to include your code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub SplitFile()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim x As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim last As Long
Dim sht As String
Dim newBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim Workbk As Excel.Workbook

Dim dir As String
    dir = Range("F12").Value

'Specify sheet name in which the data is stored
Sheets("Data").Select
sht = "Data"

'Workbook where VBA code resides
Set Workbk = ThisWorkbook

'filter column
last = Workbk.Sheets(sht).Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row

With Workbk.Sheets(sht)
Set rng = .Range("A1:M" & last)
End With

Workbk.Sheets(sht).Range("I1:M" & last).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("AA1"), Unique:=True
For Each x In Workbk.Sheets(sht).Range([AA2], Cells(Rows.Count, "AA").End(xlUp))

If Not GetWorksheet(x.Text) Is Nothing Then
Sheets(x.Text).Delete
End If

With rng



.AutoFilter
.AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:=x.Value
.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A1").Select
    Columns("A:M").Select
    Columns("A:M").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("A1").Select

    Dim Path1 As String

    Dim myfilename As String

    myfilename1 = Range("E2")
    myfilename = Range("I2")


    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=dir & "\" & myfilename1 & " - " & myfilename & ".xls", FileFormat:=xlNormal

    ActiveWorkbook.Close

End With
Next x


' Turn off filter
Workbk.Sheets(sht).AutoFilterMode = False

    Sheets("Control").Select

With Application
.CutCopyMode = False
.ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I got it to work. may not be the cleanest or most efficient but is doing what I need.